# Why do i get the url as /login/login when the submit button is pressed?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

The following is my servlet program for role based authentication

the below is the `Filter`

```
@WebFilter("/loginFilter")
public class LoginCheckFilter implements Filter {
  public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException { 
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Boolean adminURI = request.getRequestURI().endsWith("login/admin/adminAccount");
    Boolean userURI = request.getRequestURI().endsWith("login/user/userAccount");
    System.out.println(session.getAttribute("userName"));
    if(request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/login")){
        chain.doFilter(req,resp);
    } else if(session.getAttribute("userName") != null && session.getAttribute("userRole").equals("user") && adminURI){
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    } else if(session.getAttribute("userName") == null){
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    } else
        chain.doFilter(req,resp);
  }

  public void destroy() {}
}
```

I haved mapped this filter to a pattern of `/*` , and the login servlet is

```
   @WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
         throws ServletException, IOException {
       String userName, password;
        userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        password = request.getParameter("password");

        LoginService loginService = new LoginService();

        DataAccessObject dataAccessObject = new DataAccessObject();
        dataAccessObject.setUserName(userName);
        dataAccessObject.setPassword(password);
        String result = loginService.authenticate(dataAccessObject);
        if(result.equals("admin")){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("userName", userName);
            session.setAttribute("userRole", result);
            response.sendRedirect("admin/adminAccount");
            return;
        }
        else if(result.equals("user")){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("userName", userName);
            session.setAttribute("userRole", result);
            response.sendRedirect("user/userAccount");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

when I enter the url `localhost:8080/login` I get a login screen, but when i enter the `id and password` and press submit, the request is send to `localhost:8080/login/login` , I am new to servlet and dont understand why it is happening.
my `index.jsp` has login in its action. When I map my servlet to `@WebServlet("/login/login")`, then only it seems to run. What mistake have I done?
my understanding is that, after the browser goes to the servlet the request should be made to the `localhost:8080/login/` and then according to the condition, it should transfer the page to `localhost:8080/login/admin/adminAccount` or `/user/userAccount`
, my `index.jsp` is inside a login folder in the web directory.

the below is my jsp code

```
<form action="login" method="post">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>Username</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Login"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: where is your html/jsp page source code?

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh i have added the code, please see the edited version

Comment: when your are putting URL as `localhost:8080/login` you get a login page now when you do a submit as you have defined the submit action as `<form action="login" method="post">` its appending it and making the url as `localhost:8080/login/login` also first `login` is your webapplication name correct me if am not wrong. so either correct meaningfull webapplication name :P or let it be , its working in a correct way.

Comment: could you also post the `servlet` and `filter` mappings

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh my ApplicationContext is "/" so no application name is embedded. That is what it is confusing me, my application name is JSPDemo.

Comment: @GauthamanSahadevan  my web.xml consists only of the filter, with the <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

Comment: @Mohendra then better you put your `<form action="/login" method="post">` like this.

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh but should the login forms action be redirected to the loginServlet, making it /login would give me an error

Comment: can u show us how you have stored your `ApplicationContext is "/"`.

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh for intellij IDEA, the configuration for tomcat, in the deployment tab, i chose the applicationcontext to be "/"

Answer (score 0):

Your jsp is rendered in case someone enters `/login`, but than your `action="login"` will send you (since it is relatively) to `[current location="/login"]/login`.

Try to change the action to `action="/login"`. That should solve the problem.

Comment: it is not helping, the loginServlet is not being called when i set the action to /login

Comment: But what URL does is link to then?

Comment: it opens the login form, and when the id and password are entered, it stays on the same page,

Comment: What I mean is: When you submit the formular, a request should be triggered. Calling `/login` should execute the servlet, have you set a breakpoint/println() to verify that the servlet is not executed? Is there something else going wrong in-there?

Comment: yes i have, the servlet is not being executed, i tried using the breakpoint, my if statements might be wrong i guess